# QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError when executing a series of queries in a single transaction

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I add an `OnMoudleInit`service to initialize some sample data in my NestJS application.

TypeORM provides several approaches to wrap the queries into a single transcation.

I tried to use `EntityManager.transaction` to wrap the operations.

```js
 await this.manager.transaction(async (manager) => {
      // NOTE: you must perform all database operations using the given manager instance
      // it's a special instance of EntityManager working with this transaction
      // and don't forget to await things here
      const del = await manager.delete(PostEntity, {});
      console.log('posts deleted: ', del.affected);

      const userDel = await manager.delete(UserEntity, {});
      console.log('users deleted: ', userDel.affected);

      const user = new UserEntity();
      Object.assign(user, {
        firstName: 'hantsy',
        lastName: 'bai',
        email: 'hantsy@gmail.com',
      });
      const savedUser = await manager.save(user);
      console.log('saved user: ', JSON.stringify(savedUser));
      this.data.forEach(async (d) => {
        const p = new PostEntity();
        p.author = savedUser;
        
        // comment out these relation settings it will work well.
        // 
        // const comment = new CommentEntity();
        // comment.content = 'test comment at:' + new Date();
        // p.comments = Promise.resolve([comment]);
        Object.assign(p, d);
        await manager.save(p);
      });
    });

    const savedPosts = await this.postRepository.find({});
    console.log('saved:', JSON.stringify(savedPosts));
  }
```

When the application is starting up, the following error occurred.

```sh
posts deleted:  2
users deleted:  1
saved user:  {"firstName":"hantsy","lastName":"bai","email":"hantsy@gmail.com","id":"04d5cc63-d36a-4d80-a37f-97424ef168a8"}
D:\hantsylabs\nestjs-graphql-sample\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError.js:10
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
                           ^

QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore.
    at new QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError (D:\hantsylabs\nestjs-graphql-sample\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError.js:10:28)
```

**Update**: I found this is caused by the post/comment `cascade` settings, I was trying to use one command to save post/comments.

```js
  @OneToMany((type) => CommentEntity, (comment) => comment.post, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  comments?: Promise<CommentEntity[]>;
```

**Update 2**: If I use the `Repository` class to execute the `save` task, it seems it works.

```js
    const post = new PostEntity();
    post.title = 'test title';
    post.content = 'test content';
    const comment = new CommentEntity();
    comment.content = 'test comment';
    post.comments = Promise.resolve([comment]);
    await this.postRepository.save(post);
    //console.log('saved from repository: ', JSON.stringify(savedPost));
```

When I added the above codes before the manager transaction block, and I found the `manager.delete(Post, {})` did not apply the `cascade` settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got the answer from Nestjs/TypeORM discord discusstion.

Chnage the following codes to:

```js
this.data.forEach(async (d) => {
        const p = new PostEntity();
        p.author = savedUser;
        
        // comment out these relation settings it will work well.
        // 
        // const comment = new CommentEntity();
        // comment.content = 'test comment at:' + new Date();
        // p.comments = Promise.resolve([comment]);
        Object.assign(p, d);
        await manager.save(p);
      });
```

to this, use `Promise.all` to wrap all async codes.

```js
      await Promise.all(
        this.data.map(async (d) => {
          const p = new PostEntity();
          Object.assign(p, d);
          p.author = user;

          const c = CommentEntity.of('test comment at:' + new Date());
          p.comments = Promise.resolve([c]);
          await mgr.save(p);
        }),
      );
    });
```

Comment: OMG, I love you. I have been looking for a solution for two hours now. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @AfsharMohebi here's how:

In the first example `forEach` fires all async functions and the code continues with execution, eventually exiting the function, and the transaction. The manager.save(p) method probably has some promise chain inside which executes long after the transaction is gone.

`await Promise.all`, on the other hand, does not let the execution resume until all of the promises passed to Promise.all are resolved.

You can also achieve a similar (but sequential) result like this:
`for (const d of this.data) {await manager.save(new PostEntity())}`

Comment: Promise and data.map instead of forEach works perfectly!

Comment: superb, but would like to know more on why data.map works and foreach does not works

Comment: I may be late to the party but, @msonowal, that's because map() would return the values of iterable which Promise.all() requires while forEach() doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's silly, but for me, the issue was that I simply was trying to reuse a QueryRunner that's already "released". If you check TypeORM documentation https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/query-runner you will see each QueryRunner has a function to release() it manually, and there is also a boolean **property called "isReleased"** on the QueryRunner instance so if it is released you just have to **create a new QueryRunner** before running your queries.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant answer by Hantsy. You just have to wrap your map function by using await Promise.all . Like this:

```
await Promise.all(
     grn_items.map(async item => {
const itemdata = { grn: { ...grnData }, ...item };
const grnItemData = await queryRunner.manager.save(GrnItem, itemdata);
}),
            );
```

Comment: Thank you Hantsy. Love you. You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used custom repository:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
        - super(dataSource.getRepository(UserEntity).target, dataSource.manager, dataSource.createQueryRunner());
        + super(UserEntity, dataSource.manager);
    }
}
```

Sometimes after database disconnection I've got the error (*queryrunneralreadyreleasederror: query runner already released*).
So I removed query runner initialization as above.